# Rails form dropdown using two text_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu

I am creating a form has a drop down selection. I want to use two "text_method"s for the input but I am unsure how to do this. I want to include the year and name (both are two different columns in my rails model.

Here is what I have but it does not work:

```
<%= f.collection_select :bat_id, Bat.all, :id, :model_year, :model_name, include_blank: true %>
```

Here is the official documentation- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

Comment: Is what you are wanting to have the model_year and model_name shown for each Bat?

Comment: yes this is exactly what I was trying to do! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your view:

```
<%= f.collection_select :bat_id, Bat.all, :id, :model_year_and_name, include_blank: true %>
```

Add a method like this to your Bat model:

```
def model_year_and_name
    "#{model_year} #{model_name}"
end
```